# Python Selenium find next Element after an Element is found

Tags: python, selenium, siblings, findelement

I got some problems to find the right element using Selenium. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <label></label>
                <label></label>
                <select></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Can’t publish the original URL due its company use only)

In the HTML Code there multiple (count changes every time) Tables looking like the Code above. To find the correct Table I am using this Code:

```
for index, table in enumerate(self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//table/thead/tr/th[{column}]')):
    if table.text == header_text: break

main_table = self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//table')[index]
```

Works fine for me, the problem is that I need to identify the select tag after the correct table as well.
Can anyone help me out with this Code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//table/thead/tr/th[{column}]')
```

this will return a list. you can go to select tag by using the below XPath:

```
list_of_th = self.browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//table/thead/tr/th[{column}]')
select_web_element = list_of_th[0].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//ancestor::table/../../../following-sibling::div[2]/descendant::select")
```

should get the job done.